# Bash - change path to the folder with the highest version number

Tags: bash, directory, cd

I have the below folder structure

```
MyPackage
  └── versions
      └── MyPackage-1.0
          └── src
          MyPackage-1.0.1
          └── src
          MyPackage-2.0
          └── src
```

I am writing a bash script to build the latest version of the package and retrieve the build artifact. Part of that step is to change to the directory of the latest package:

```
cd MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-2.0/src
```

How can I write my bash script such that it will always choose the highest version subfolder (so in this case `MyPackage-2.0` but in the future it could become `MyPackage-2.0.1` or `MyPackage-2.1`)?

Comment: I would strongly recommend adding `MyPackage/latest -> MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-2.0'` (e.g.) as a symlink to whatever is the newest version. Don't make everybody else have to work to figure out what the installer already knows.

Comment: For example, whoever puts `MyPackage-2.1` in `versions/` is responsible for updating `MyPackage/latest`.

Comment: @chepner That's worth an answer I would say ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not the creator of the package (although I called it MyPackage in the example I used) so creating a symlink would help me (but be more of a pain than this automated script) and nobody else.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths How do new versions arrive, though? And how do you *know* it wouldn't help anyone else?

Comment: There is a central git repo. Whenever you build the package from that repo it executes a build script that clones the latest version of a different git repo (the package in question) into a folder with its version number. To get the symlink out to everyone else I'd have to create it and then get a pull request approved by the owners of the repo every time the version updates (which is frequently). If I did all that, then yes, it would help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of GNU sort you can do the following:

```
cd "$(printf "%s"$'\n' MyPackage/versions/* | sort -Vr | head -n1)"
```

Broken down:

```
$ printf "%s"$'\n' MyPackage/versions/*
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-1.0
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-1.0.1
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-2.0
$ printf "%s"$'\n' MyPackage/versions/* | sort -Vr
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-2.0
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-1.0.1
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-1.0
$ printf "%s"$'\n' MyPackage/versions/* | sort -Vr | head -n1
MyPackage/versions/MyPackage-2.0
```

Comment: Assuming you have a version of `sort` whose `-h` does the necessary thing.

Comment: Don't you want `-V` for version sort?

Comment: @BenjaminW. True, changed

Comment: @hek2mgl You changed your example line to -V, but not the breakdown.