# Bash - select the only file in a directory

Tags: bash

I have a bash script and I need to make use of a file. I do not know the name of this file but I can guarantee that it is the only file in the directory. For example:

```
MyFolder
  └── unknown_name.txt
```

In a bash script how can I refer to and manipulate `unknown_name.txt`?

Comment: This is another case (like your [previous question on versioned directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805676/bash-change-path-to-the-folder-with-the-highest-version-number)) where having a well-defined directory layout would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: In this case, it is clean. I simplified. The file name can be known, however to determine its name at run time would require executing several commands, which is more complicated than simply using find in this case.

Comment: By "known", I mean known *before* you run the script.

Comment: I'm creating a script that automatically compiles the latest version of an app, for the architecture of the computer, and the latest version. The name changes based upon the architecture of the computer and the current latest build, so a human can easily identify exactly what build it is. Making the names uniform and known before I run the script would mean people would have to decompile the package to find out what architecture it was made for, and what version it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use globbing:

```
nano MyFolder/*
```

Or `find`:

```
nano "$(find MyFolder/ -type f)"
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw globbing before but for the specific tool I'm using it verifies the file extension is correct so find worked for me!

Comment: `nano MyFolder/*.txt`